# Can I make my Lua program to sleep for AROUND a day?

Tags: lua, sleep, duration, seconds

I want to make my mydicebot (by seuntje) Lua program sleep AROUND A DAY, after betting for a day... like

```
function sleep(n)
  t = os.clock()
  while os.clock() - t <= n do
    -- nothing
  end
end

function playsleep() 
  sec = math.random(80000,90000) 
  sleep(sec)     -- around 86400 seconds
end

timestart = os.time() 
dur = math.random(70000,80000)


function dobet() 
   if os.time() - timestart < math.random then
      playsleep()
   end
   timestart = os.time()     -- reset the time counter
end
```

but when I call the playsleep function in the dobet function

1. it ends up I cannot click anything in my program, cannot move another tab also
2. and the CPU is not sleeping either, even get busy
3. and sometimes it stucks even after 90000 seconds

-- THE QUESTIONS --

A. so can I make a function where the sleep is a real sleep?

B. can it sleep until 90000 seconds?

C. or what is the max number of sleep in seconds for the variable "sec" above?

Comment: You could use python's `time.sleep(sec) ` instead of implementing your own sleep method.

Comment: i am using Lua sir, sorry for forgetting to mention.. could you please?

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction

Answer (score 0):

Use the posix module to sleep:

```
posix = require("posix")
posix.sleep(86400)
```

But this will still block your program and you won't be able to click anything. You will need to provide more detail about your program in order to receive better advice.

Comment: i use this to run mydicebot, sleep around 1 whole day after betting around 1 whole day

Answer (score 0):

Also `os` is there.
Why not...

```
do os.execute('$(type -path sleep) '..(3600*24)) end
```

...?

Comment: not working bro, thanks for your suggestion btw... do I need to find the sleep command first? or just I type like you typed here?

Comment: This depends on operating system, sorry for that. My example runs on linux where ```$(type -path sleep)``` results to ```/bin/sleep```